# Docker / latest not found while DockerFile exists

Tags: docker

I have docker file, and I wish to run it at my coreos machine .

I run:
`docker run cloudflare/kafka_zookeeper_exporter` but it says:
`Error: image cloudflare/kafka_zookeeper_exporter:latest not found.`
while DockerFile exists:

https://github.com/cloudflare/kafka_zookeeper_exporter

what can be the reason and how can I use this branch as docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a docker image, it's a Github code repository. What you need to do instead is `docker build -t kafka_zookeeper_exporter . && docker run -ti kafka_zookeeper_exporter` so it will build the `Dockerfile` with the tag `kafka_zookeeper_exporter` on your local machine, and then you will run that image as a container

Edit 1:
make sure you download that github repo first by doing `git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/kafka_zookeeper_exporter.git`